# Instant Apps: Use feature module from base module without strong dependency

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to implement new Instant App feature in my Android app. I have 4 modules:

- Base feature module with all Activities and logic: `base`
- Feature module with push notifications classes: `push`
- Installed app module: `installed`
- Instant app module: `instant`

Since Instant App doesn't support push notifications, I want to enable `push` module only for installed app. But I have shared classes in `base` that call `push` methods. For example, I initialize `push` module during app startup in Application class.

How do I organise dependencies, so I don't have to include `push` module to `base` module, but being able to call `push` methods from `base`? I have an idea that I can create interface `PushManagerProvider` in `base` module so `instant` and `installed` can provide their own implementations, but I'm not sure how can I inject concrete implementation to `base` depending on current module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use dagger and that you build a singleton component in your Application class, here's one approach.

In `base`, define an `Injector` interface that your `@Component` class extends. Have your Application in your base module implement an `InjectorProvider` interface that has a single `getInjector()` method that returns your constructed component. That component will be built using a module that provides a no-op `PushManagerProvider`.

Then in your `push` module, create an alternative implementation of your `Application` class (extend your base and rename to `PushAwareApplication`?) That creates a component using a dagger module that provides a legit `PushManagerProvider` and use [merge rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_rule_markers) to force use of the new `PushAwareApplication` name when push is built into your application module.

This way you can call

```
((InjectorProvider)getApplication()).getInjector().inject(this);
```

And get a different component implementation depending on whether you built the installable app or the instant app.

There are probably more correct ways of doing this with dagger, but this should get you started.

If you're not using dagger, you can use the same Application override technique described above with both Application implementations implementing an interface that offers a 'getPushManagerProvider()` method.